# Lisp: atom and string

Tags: lisp, tokenize

I am working on a simple Lisp interpreter. And now I am trying to write a parser for it. [LISP - Basic Syntax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lisp/lisp_basic_syntax.htm). I've read that in Lisp there are only three types of block: `atom`, `list`, `string`. Also, I've noticed that `string` block can be nested into the `list`, like:

`(format t "Some string block...~%")`.

Could `string` type of building block be considered as `atom` block?

Comment: In Lisp any data type which is not a cons cell is an atom.

Comment: If you are making a simple basic lisp then you might be interested in [The roots of Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, the pages you chose as a "reference" are of a *very* dubious quality. The most obvious visual red flag if the "unconventional" (to put it mildly) way to format Lisp code.

**Second**, [`block`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_block.htm) in Lisp has a very specific meaning. When they use that word they, *apparently*, mean [`token`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_c.htm).

**Third**, the [`string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_string.htm) type in Lisp is a subtype of type [`atom`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_atom.htm):

```
(atom "foo")
==> t
```

Thus, the answer to the question you asked is: yes, every string is an atom.

And the answer to the question you should have asked is: refer to [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/Front/), not to some dubious web site.

**PS**. There are several [FLOSS](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/floss-and-foss.en.html) Common Lisp implementations available (e.g.,
[CLISP](http://clisp.org), [SBCL](http://sbcl.org)), 
you might want to start with looking how they do things.

Comment: Sorry, one off-topic question. What `(terpri)` function does?

Comment: @KuznetsovSergey http://clhs.lisp.se/Front/X_Perm_T.htm ==> http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_terpri.htm#terpri